# Can System.Web be used within a class library that targets .net standard 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, forms-authentication, .net-standard-2.0

I have an Asp.net application that uses form authentication. I am building an asp.net core API that will receive a JWT token that has user information included in the payload. This API needs to call asp.net application for serving the user request. In order for asp.net application to serve this request, it needs the form authentication cookie to recognize it as valid logged in user.

**In other words, the API needs to generate and send an authentication cookie in the request forwarding stimulating scenario that actual user is making the request.**

**Note:**
The API is being created to expose features of the asp.net application as a public API without user having to log in to the asp.net application UI directly first.

I am creating a class library that target .net standard 2.0 that can be used in my api that takes care of creating cookie part and add it to the request before it forwards the request to my asp.net application. How can I create FormAuthenication cookie in my class library? I found following code and wondering how can I do similar in my library?

```
string userData = string.Join("|",GetCustomUserRoles());

  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,                                     // ticket version
    username,                              // authenticated username
    DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),           // expiryDate
    isPersistent,                          // true to persist across browser sessions
    userData,                              // can be used to store additional user data
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie

  // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
  string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

  // Add the cookie to the request to save it
  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
  cookie.HttpOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `System.Web` is .NET Framework only. It is not included nor compatible with .NET Standard, any version. Additionally, Forms Auth, in general, is deprecated (as part of ASP.NET Membership), so nothing but ASP.NET (.NET Framework) will ever be able to work with it.

Going forward, if you need to share authentication, you must switch to ASP.NET (Core) Identity and utilize the data protection API, rather than the old-style machine key encryption Forms Auth depends on.

For what it's worth though, an API should not be using cookie authentication. Cookies are a non-standard way for clients to interact with an API, and they're also a form of state, whereas APIs should be stateless (REST). Instead, you should be doing something like basic or bearer authentication, using the `Authorization` header to authorize each request either with user/pass (basic) or token (bearer).

Comment: Thanks. The API will be using Bearer authentication for its usage but it needs to forward this request to asp.net application which uses the form authentication. In future the whole processing will be implemented in API itself. For now, it is sort of first step to make features available quickly and then eventually migrate those features into API.